# Spring Security, keep remember-me token valid after password change

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, remember-me

My issue is when a user changes their password, the remember-me token is no longer valid. Which makes sense, but is pretty annoying due to how often the password is changed in my application.

I would like remember-me tokens to persist, even after a password is changed. Is this possible?

Comment: That would be a security issue. What if the password is compromised. The malicious actor would still have the ”remember me token” even if you changed the password.

Comment: There's going to be an option to invalidate the account sessions.

Comment: As @Toerktumlare said, it is a security issue. But if you really want to do this, use the `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices` implementation or implement your own.